# pass a div content to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I strip the quotes and pass the hex value to jquery so each values can be used as background color?

```
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff1 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff2 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff3 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff4 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff5 " </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".someclass").hover(
      function() {
          //mouse over
          $(this).css('background', '*pass it here*')
      }, function() {
          //mouse out
          $(this).css('background', '')
      });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There are a lot of good answers below. Please help the community by upvoting and choosing the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
$(this).css('background', this.innerHTML.replace(/[" ]/g, ''))
```

The code above, explained:

- **`this.innerHTML`** = Gets the div's inside content
- **`/[" ]/g`** = Regex grabbing all quotes (`"`) and spaces ()
- **`.replace()`** = Function used to remove what is found by the regex, leaving only the HEX code of your color.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to extract just the `#xxxxxx` part and remove the rest:

```
var color = /#[0-9a-f]+/.exec($(this).html())[0];
$(this).css('background', color)
```

Also, you only have 5 characters for the colors, normally should be 6 characters.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".someclass").hover(
      function() {
          var color = /#[0-9a-f]+/.exec($(this).html())[0];
          $(this).css('background', color)
      }, function() {
          $(this).css('background', '')
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass"> " #ff0011 " </div>
<div class="someclass"> extra things " #ff0022 " </div>
<div class="someclass"> " #aaff00 " some other things </div>
<div class="someclass">123 " #ff00ff " 456</div>
<div class="someclass"> " #002233 " </div>
```

Comment: would break if a color like "red" is used

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. You're right, but OP asked for passing "hex value".

Comment: @TheNagaTanker Happy to help :) Please consider choosing a best answer if the issue is resolved ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff1 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff2 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff3 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff4 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff5 " </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".someclass").hover(
      function() {
          //mouse over
          $(this).css('background', $(this).html().replace(/\"/g , ""));
      }, function() {
          //mouse out
          $(this).css('background', '')
      });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: It's not going to work as `.replace()` is not a jquery function.

Comment: @UtkarshVishnoi `.html()` returns a string, and replace is a string function.

Answer (score 0):

This checks to see if there are quotes or not, so they are optional.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".someclass").hover(
    function() {
      //mouse over
      var color = $(this).html().trim();
      if(color[0] === '"' && color[color.length-1] === '"'){
       color = color.substring(1, color.length-2).trim();
      }
      $(this).css('background', color)
    }, function() {
      //mouse out
      $(this).css('background', '')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass"> " red " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #000 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #000123 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> " #123123 " </div>
 <div class="someclass"> green </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to split the string and extract the hex code:

```
let color = $(this).html().split(' ')[2];
$(this).css('background', color);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".someclass").hover(
    function() {
      //mouse over
      let color = $(this).html().split(' ')[2];
      $(this).css('background', color);
    }, function() {
      //mouse out
      $(this).css('background', '')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass"> " #ffff12 " </div>
<div class="someclass"> " #aaff23 " </div>
<div class="someclass"> " #bbff34 " </div>
<div class="someclass"> " #ccff45 " </div>
<div class="someclass"> " #ddff56 " </div>
```

Comment: clever but doesn't account for the quotes

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Seems to work fine though, on the given input.

Comment: i must have been looking at a different answe when i posted that, because assuming that space is there is does account for the quotes, but given input has a space even before that, so on the given input the index would be one greater.

Comment: You're right. The extra spaces got trimmed off when I tidied off the code snippet. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
textColor = $(this).html(); //get text
textColor= textColor.replace('"',''); //remove the quotes
textColor= textColor.replace(/\s+/g, ''); //remove spaces
$(this).css('background', textColor); //use
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the color code using regex with help of [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass">" #ffff10 "</div>
<div class="someclass">" #ffff20 "</div>
<div class="someclass">" #ffff30 "</div>
<div class="someclass">" #ffff40 "</div>
<div class="someclass">" #ffff50 "</div>
<div class="someclass">" #156 "</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".someclass").hover(
      function() {
        //mouse over
        $(this).css('background', $(this).text().match(/#(?:[\da-f]{6}|[\da-f]{3})/i)[0])
      }, function() {
        //mouse out
        $(this).css('background', '')
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what if a 3 digit color is used? or a string like "black"?

Comment: the # prevents this form working with strings like "red" or "black"

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. : ___"how can I strip the quotes and pass the hex value"___

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this code

```
 $(".someclass").hover(function() {
         $(this).css('background-color', $(this).html().replace('"','').replace(' ',''));
    }
, function() {
    $( this ).css(  'background-color', '');
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

replace `$(this).css('background', '*pass it here*')` with

```
$(this).css('background', $(this).html())
```